# Retrieving float value from table

Tags: mysql

I have a field in a table "url_key_weight" with float data type. In one record i have value 2.95 in the float field. 
When I retrieve and print it from PHP code, it prints 2.9500000476837. 
But when I run the following querys from PHP

```
"SELECT * FROM url_key_weight WHERE bid = 2.95"
```

OR

```
"SELECT * FROM url_key_weight WHERE bid = 2.9500000476837"
```

I get nothing.

Comment: @fancyPants url_key_weight is table name and bid is column name. and yes bid is float

Comment: Try enclosing the numbers in quotes vis '2.95' and see what happens.  Is your field type defined as float?  Would varchar perhaps be a better way to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567434/mysql-floating-point-comparison-issues

Comment: Why are you using FLOAT at all? DECIMAL would seem more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a direct compare you'd have to round

```
SELECT * FROM url_key_weight WHERE ROUND(bid, 2) = 2.95
```

Read more about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round).

Comment: So? Do you want to get that row, too? Or is it returning this row although you don't want to?

Comment: Also, if you care so much about having correct values, then you should use the decimal datatype instead of float.

Answer (score 0):

```
it is not generally a good idea to compare floating point numbers with = equals operator.
```

try out this

```
"SELECT * FROM url_key_weight WHERE bid >= 2.95"
```

Comment: But I have another value 2.96 in bid