# Subtraction of two equal values is not zero in mysql

Tags: mysql

Why Subtraction of two equal values in mysql does not equal zero?

both field type are double. See image below
[image]

Comment: those field are double. @MitchWheat

Comment: Obligatory link: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Quantities should NOT be double. Make them integer

Comment: @KenWhite, Obligatory upvote to obligatory link :). OP: TL;DR: You're going to have errors if you use floating point numbers, in this case the value is tiny, so it won't make much of a difference if you're using it in further arithmetic operations

Answer (score 3):

That's known as a approximate **precision** . This isn't an error, [floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) data types are intended to work such way. They can not store data precisely. So if that matters, you should use fixed-point data types, such as [`DECIMAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fixed-point-types.html) in MySQL.

On the other hand, you can always use precision delta for comparisons for floating point, like:

```
SELECT 
  `foo`,
  `bar`,
  IF(ABS(`foo`-`bar`)<1E-13, 0, `foo`-`bar`) AS zero_compared
FROM
 t
```

as you can see, here delta is `1E-13` (normally, that will be enough)

Comment: Actually I have to develop a inventory management software. where inventory quantities might be in 5 decimal place so that I use double. lets I have a product with 19.87 quantity in a store. when i try to transfer 19.87 quantity to another store it show not enough quantity to transfer. Now I how can I manage it.

Comment: Use `DECIMAL` for that. Your values will be stored precisely

Comment: How can there be "a product with 19.87 quantity in a store?

Comment: @MitchWheat product unit is kg or mg. So it could be 19.87 kg

Comment: @ Md. Sahadat Hossain: that seems extremely unlikely

Answer (score 1):

This problem is due to floating point precision and calculations on them.
You can also refer this Issue for clarity on your problem:

[MySQL floating point comparison issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567434/mysql-floating-point-comparison-issues)