# When I add xx to mysql float column, it is wrong result, Is it a bug?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

My mysql:
   5.6.16

my table info :

```
CREATE TABLE `xxx` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `money` float(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00' ,
  `real_money` float(10,2) NOT NULL ,
  `available_invoice` float(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;
```

my table content is :

```
1    100000.00      0.00    0.01
30   99992560.00    0.03    0.00
61   65216.00       0.03    0.00
79   10.00          0.00    0.00
80   10.00          0.00    0.00
81   -70.00         0.00    0.00
83   60.00          0.00    0.00
100  100.00         50.00   50.00
889  980.00         0.00    0.00
1234 99959040.00    0.00    99999.00
1239 40.00          0.00    0.00
```

when I execute the sql :

```
update `xxx` set `money`=`money`-20 where uid = 1234
```

the result is :

```
uid  money          real_money available_invoice
1    100000.00      0.00    0.01
30   99992560.00    0.03    0.00
61   65216.00       0.03    0.00
79   10.00          0.00    0.00
80   10.00          0.00    0.00
81   -70.00         0.00    0.00
83   60.00          0.00    0.00
100  100.00         50.00   50.00
889  980.00         0.00    0.00
1234 99959024.00    0.00    99999.00
1239 40.00          0.00    0.00
```

it is always miss 4 or 2 whatever I add or subtracts some to a float number which is nearly 100000000, why ?

Comment: I don't have an exact answer, but using `decimal(10,2)` might fix this problem.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226700/subtraction-of-two-equal-values-is-not-zero-in-mysql) for more information.

Comment: Do you happen to have an insert script? So I can easily recreate your problem?

Comment: @gordlonious        INSERT INTO `xxx` (`uid`, `money`, `real_money`, `available_invoice`)
VALUES
 (1, 100000.00, 0.00, 0.01),
 (30, 312.00, 0.03, 0.00),
 (61, 65216.00, 0.03, 0.00),
 (79, 10.00, 0.00, 0.00),
 (80, 10.00, 0.00, 0.00),
 (81, -70.00, 0.00, 0.00),
 (83, 60.00, 0.00, 0.00),
 (100, 100.00, 50.00, 50.00),
 (889, 980.00, 0.00, 0.00),
 (1234, 100000.00, 0.00, 99999.00),
 (1239, 40.00, 0.00, 0.00);

Comment: Money is almost always DECIMAL

Comment: In [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb128/1) it is working fine!!

Comment: Try it in mysql. I reenacted the problem exactly. the `money` column should be either `decimal` or `numeric`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has something to do with how large your floating point value is but I'm not 100% sure why. I tested updating a similar row with smaller numbers and it worked fine. You should also refrain from using quotes wherever possible as it requires extra processing. See this SO question: [update a column by subtracting a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383108/update-a-column-by-subtracting-a-value)

Here is my easy work-around just like Tim Biegeleisen suggested:

```
CREATE TABLE `xxx` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `money` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00' ,
  `real_money` float(10,2) NOT NULL ,
  `available_invoice` float(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;
```

Insert:

```
USE dbname;
insert into xxx Values(1234, 99959040.00, 0.00, 99999.00);
```

Update without strings:

```
update xxx set money = money - 20 where uid = 1234;
```

There are some odd things when calculating with large floating point values. Some of these issues are machine-dependent and are related to what type of processor you have. Read more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-float.html

Also, according to another SO question floating point values are NOT a good way to store money values. [Difference between float and decimal data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150274/difference-between-float-and-decimal-data-type) (see the second answer).

It seems that using `decimal` and `numeric` data types are best for money columns in mysql.