# MySQL request return results when call from console, but empty when request using ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii2

I have strange problem. Im using Yii2 (latest stable).
I have table with some filters for diamond base. One of filters r float (Weight).

When i trying to filter from 1.1 to 1.2 - i see results in array from active record. When im trying to request 1.1 to 1.1 (exact weight) yii returns empty array.

I try to copy request from debug toolbar end execute it in mysql console and mysql returns all results correctly.

Request:

```
SELECT `Diamonds`.* FROM `Diamonds` 
    LEFT JOIN `DiamondsSpecialGroups` 
        ON `Diamonds`.`specialGroup` = `DiamondsSpecialGroups`.`id` 
        WHERE (((((`endPrice` >= 500) 
        AND (`type` IN (0, 1, 2, 3))) AND ((`active`=1) 
        AND (`internalBlock`=0) 
        AND (`frontendHide`=0))) 
        AND (`Weight`=0.39)) 
        AND (`endPrice` >= '500')) 
        AND (`endPrice` <= '1323231') 
    ORDER BY `endPrice` 
    LIMIT 50
```

If i remove

```
(`Weight`=0.39)
```

All results sowing both in mysql and yii.

Finally question - why?

Comment: It is quite hard with `=` and floats. Floats are never 100% accurate I think the issue might be that the translation from ruby to mysql might change the value of your `0.39` the slightest.

Comment: This is a more elaborate answer on the issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567434/mysql-floating-point-comparison-issues

Comment: Thank you! After changing FLOAT to DECIMAL all seems works good!

Comment: @Albin You should issue that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite hard with `=` and floats.

Floats are never 100% accurate I think the issue might be that two different instances of `0.39` differs a little bit from one another.

In order to avoid this you could use DECIMAL instead of FLOAT as suggested in the answer I posted below.

[More elaborate answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567434/mysql-floating-point-comparison-issues)

Comment: Good note, but how it relates to Ruby?

Comment: I think it is general for all languages. You should avoid equal for floats.

Comment: Yes, but I think it's better to remove Ruby mention from answer.

Comment: Good point. I updated the answer according to your suggestion.