# MySQL bug when adding two REAL values together

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How come when I run this code, I get an output of 0.21000000000000002 instead of 0.21?

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE S1 REAL;
    DECLARE S2 REAL;
    DECLARE Srainfall REAL;
    SET S1 = .04;
    SET S2 = .17;
    SET Srainfall = S1 + S2;
    Insert into Statistical_info(City_id, Total_Rain_fall)
    values(ID, Srainfall);
END
```

Comment: Floating point errors

Comment: Your "bug" is called floating point precision. [This answer explains it for mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2567509/4205652).

Comment: as Intel once said, it's close enough for you (they caught crap for that)