# Deleting a row based on a float column in Mysql/PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

This

```
DELETE FROM `z_ratings` 
WHERE `score` = '5.4' 
  AND `media_id` = '242' 
  AND `user_id` = '1'
```

will not delete the following row:

[image]

Can anybody explain why?

(I'm assuming the issue is with the float since both other columns are integers)

Comment: @Abdulla This is the query generated by active records in Codeigniter though. I'll check if there is a way to remove those single quotes

Comment: Can you switch type to decimal? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567434

Comment: Share table  `z_ratings` creation script

Comment: @lad2025 user_id INT, media_id INT, score FLOAT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the floating point column.  You can review the issues with this representation and comparisons.  One place to start is the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-float.html).

Great, we know it doesn't work.  More importantly, what can you do?

Probably the most accurate solution is to switch to decimal, say `decimal(5, 1)` for the column.  Then, this shouldn't be a problem.

Alternatively, use `abs()` and difference for a fuzzy comparison:

```
abs(score - 3.4) < 0.0001
```

Comment: Looks like this is the issue. I'm going to see if that works.

Comment: @gordon-lindoff and that is in fact correct. thanks for the help