# Result not valid for sum from another table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 table

tbl1

```
INSERT INTO `tbl1` (`id_tbl1`, `name`, `weight`) VALUES
(1, 'data_1', 0.2),
(2, 'data_2', 0.3),
(3, 'data_3', 0.4),
(4, 'data_4', 0.5),
(5, 'data_5', 0.5),
(6, 'data_6', 0.9),
(7, 'data_7', 0.9),
(14, 'data_14', 0.2),
(15, 'data_15', 0.4),
(16, 'data_16', 0.6),
(17, 'data_17', 0.5),
(18, 'data_18', 0.7),
(19, 'data_19', 0.9);
```

tbl2

```
INSERT INTO `tbl2` (`id_tbl2`, `id_category`, `id_tbl1`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 2),
(3, 1, 3),
(4, 1, 4),
(5, 1, 5),
(6, 1, 6),
(7, 1, 7),
(14, 3, 14),
(15, 3, 15),
(16, 3, 16),
(17, 3, 17),
(18, 3, 18),
(19, 3, 19);
```

and this my query

```
SELECT SUM(weight)  AS 'total'
FROM tbl2
JOIN tbl1 ON tbl2.id_tbl1 = tbl1.id_tbl1 GROUP BY id_category;
```

Result should be 3.7 and 3.3 but showing

```
3.6999999999999997
3.3000000000000003
```

Can somebody tell me what is wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: change your datatype to DECIMAL to avoid floating point problems. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567434/mysql-floating-point-comparison-issues

Comment: i think its not work, because i need result is 3.7 and 3.3

Comment: Use `SELECT FORMAT(SUM(weight), 1) as total` to get the number rounded to the nearest decimal place.