# Comparing double values in mysql not seems to be working properly

Tags: mysql, database

When I compare a float value in where clause it does not give proper results.
for example

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE score = 0.61
```

in this query score is a column of double type

but the above query works if I check the score to be `0.50` nothing else is being searched while I have records with `0.61` too

The above query also work if i use

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE trim(score) = 0.61
```

Comment: score column data type ?

Comment: Yes it's working if I use `trim` function

Comment: @VivekMaru  http://stackoverflow.com/a/2567509/4248328

Comment: and what is length and decimal range you have given ?

Comment: length and range of double is 16,4 respectively

Comment: Why it is working with `0.5`

Comment: you mean if you do : score = 0.61 nothing will be shown even if you have a record with score

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use `decimal` instead of `float`. And it also have 2 decimal places only.

Here is the documentation on how to use it. [Link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html).

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: If I use decimal it automatically append 0 in remaining decimal range, for example `0.61` becomes `0.6100` and I don't need that

Comment: cast('score' AS CHAR) <=> '0.61' try this

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't did not specify the  decimal range in your float column i will not work without casting or trim:

this works fine :

```
-- drop table test_float;
create table test_float(f float(6,4) , d DECIMAL(4,2));
insert into test_float values (0.5,0.5);
insert into test_float values (0.61,0.61);
select * from test_float where f = d;
select * from test_float where f = 0.61;
```

this don't work :

```
drop table test_float;
create table test_float(f float , d DECIMAL(4,2));
insert into test_float values (0.5,0.5);
insert into test_float values (0.61,0.61);
select * from test_float;
select * from test_float where f = d;
select * from test_float where f = 0.61;
select * from test_float where CAST(f as DECIMAL(16,2)) = 0.61;
```

it work for  decimal range  `range = 1` 
why , I really don't know why ?!!